# Accessing Azure-based services inside a VM

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, acs, adfs2.0

I'm trying to access my ACS instance from ADFS v2.0 inside a VM on Azure - only, it doesn't resolve the address:
https://myacsname.accesscontrol.windows.net/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml

Playing around it seems like it won't resolve sites like http://windowsazure.com either. However I can get to many other sites just fine (Microsoft.com, Bing, Google, etc.)

Anybody come across this before?

Kind regards,
Nick

Edit: It seems like this only occurs on VMs that are using my own DNS (which I setup with the AD DS role). What needs to be changed from the default configuration for my DNS to get these particular sites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha! Figured it out, I think.

I setup my forest with the root domain 'cloudapp.net' after following a tutorial.
When I installed DNS it took control of name resolution for any sites hosted on Azure (cloudapp.net). Removing cloudapp.net from the Forward Lookup Zones fixed this for me (though I expect it will break something with AD?). Perhaps it would be better to use a different root domain.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I had faced the same issue. However if I don't use cloudapp.net then I am not able to access ADFS2.0 federation xml. Is there a workaround to access federation xml without using cloudapp.net as root domain?

Comment: You can still use cloudapp.net as the root domain
Basically, DNS takes control of anything with the *.cloudapp.net domain because it thinks it owns it now (which it normally would).
To change that: open DNS Manager and remove cloudapp.net from the 'Forward Lookup Zones'.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked to set up your own Virtual Network?  I solved this before using/controlling my own DNS servers.  This allows you to route traffic with the DIP (private network) or VIP (routing through outside the data center).

Good info here:
http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2012/AZR209

Comment: Thanks Bart - I have setup my own Virtual Network (and I have my own DNS). It seems like having my own DNS is part of the problem actually - updated the question.